# Python urllib AttributeError

Tags: python

```
import urllib.request

fhand = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.python.org")

for line in fhand:
    
    print(line.decode().strip())
```

This code isn't working, I'm using python3 on windows10. Every time I run this code in command prompt using atom editor, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\isha\Downloads\py4e\trial.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.request
  File "C:\Users\isha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "C:\Users\isha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "C:\Users\isha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "C:\Users\isha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "C:\Users\isha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\email\_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "C:\Users\isha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\email\utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Users\isha\Downloads\py4e\socket.py", line 5, in <module>
    mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
**AttributeError: partially initialized module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_INET' (most likely due to a circular import)**
```

Help me with this code, also I'm not able to run `urllib.request` and related programs

Comment: You have a file named "socket.py" in your current directory, that gets imported instead of the module of the standard library. Rename it.

Comment: with 'import socket' I'm getting the same AttributeError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works well for me. Try delete 'C:\Users\isha\Downloads\py4e\socket.py' this file and run your code again.

Comment: Thanks it's working. I don't know what the problem was with 'socket.py' but now I can run this program.